# Are uncollected engrams lost in the Haunted Forest?

Tags: destiny-2

When playing the Haunted Forest event, during the Festival of the Lost (Oct 16 to Nov 6) engrams will drop from enemies, however the transitions are quick between bosses and the next stage, due to the time pressure.

What happens to these engrams if I don't manage to collect them? I don't get anything in the Postmaster when I get back to the Tower. Are these engrams lost?

Comment: I had missed a couple blues and a purple from a nightmare yesterday and they were all at the post-master afterwards. So not sure what happened to you but I wouldn't imagine they would make it any different in that one activity and not say anything.

Comment: I assume they should be, perhaps I just missed it. If you could write an answer I could accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limited time Haunted Forest is an activity just like everything else in Destiny 2. If any item, redeemable/planetary currency, or engram drops and is not collected it will be sent to the post-master to be retrieved later. Items not found at the post-master could be due to accidentally picking them up while in the activity when you think you missed it or perhaps mistaking a blue(rare) engram for an orb of light.

Comment: It's almost embarrassing on how many times I've mistaken blue engrams as orbs of light...

Comment: I've also discovered that the Forest uses the same instance for each branch of the forest. So if you missed an engram or ammo on a previous branch it will still be there on your next branch.